# Apache Calcite query json nested data

Tags: apache-calcite

I'm done to read simple data in json format from kafka by using calcite sql. 
There is a special requirement that there is nested data like bellow

> {"DATA":{"SPEED":80},"USER_ID":100200,"USER_NAME":"user1"}

And I want **DATA.SPEED** no just **DATA** as my query criteria or where condition like bellow

> select DATA.SPEED from "database" where DATA.SPEED > 50  order by
>   USER_ID desc

Is there is way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I don't have a full solution for you, but you should be able to make use of the `JSON_VALUE` function in your WHERE clause to get the speed.